# Displaying the product into the textbox

Tags: c#

I've been getting this error whenever I run the application.

System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' on the `decimal weight = Convert.ToDecimal(txtboxWeight.Text);`

I don't know where I went wrong in this part this code is running from my different program.

```
private void ShowtotalPayment()
    {
        decimal weight = Convert.ToDecimal(txtboxWeight.Text);
        decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(lblPrice.Text);
        int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(NumQuantity.Text);
        decimal totalPayment = weight * price * quantity;

        lblTotalPayment.Text = totalPayment.ToString();

        
    };
```

Comment: You don't have a decimal value in `txtboxWeight.Text`.  Prefer `decimal.TryParse`.

Comment: @LarsTech, I get this error "No overload for method tryparse" takes 1 argument

Comment: It would help if you looked up how to use it.  See [decimal.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-5.0).  Many examples here on StackOverflow, too.

Answer (score 3):

For example, change:

```
decimal weight = Convert.ToDecimal(txtboxWeight.Text);
```

To:

```
decimal weight;
if (Decimal.TryParse(txtboxWeight.Text, out weight)) {
    // ... do something with "weight" or proceed in here ...
}
else  {
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Decimal in Weight!");
}
```